# This API is not allowed for users who have logged in to the app anonymously

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

When i was trying to connect to Facebook with my app, I received this error today, is there any change in Facebook API?, this scenario has worked since today.
error text:
(#200) This API is not allowed for users who have logged in to the app anonymously.

Comment: The error is not in your question. Can you add it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Facebook** respond :

This is fixed now. We ill keep it assigned for now to completely confirm it is being resolved.

Sorry for the inconvenience it caused to you guys.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it's a **Facebook** problem.
Keep watching here : https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/504561102998807/.